# what is the probability that the letters e, g, and k are all in the same subset?

Tags: probability

the 26 letters of the alphabet are to be randomly partitioned into subsets with 5,10, and 11 letters respectively. what is the probability that the letters e, g, and k are all in the same subset?
I am unsure about how to go about this. I have tried 3!/5!10!11! And I know that is not it and have also tried (5C3)(10C3)(11C3)/(26C3) and that isnt correst either. I just need a push in the right direction

Comment: Do you know how to count the ways of splitting 26 letters into subsets of sizes 5,10, and 11?

Comment: Once you’ve done that you can break it into three cases: egk are in the subset of size 5,10, or 11. How many ways are there for each case to happen?

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you!

Comment: I’m glad! You should write the answer yourself down below once you solve it :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $S$ is a randomly chosen subset of $\{\text{a,b,}\cdots\text{,z}\}$ having $n$ elements then:

$P(\text{e}\in S\wedge\text{g}\in S\wedge\text{k}\in S)=P(\text{e}\in S)P(\text{g}\in S\mid\text{e}\in S)P(\text{k}\in S\mid\text{g}\in S\wedge\text{e}\in S)=\frac{n}{26}\frac{n-1}{25}\frac{n-2}{24}$